# strange macro in c, using multiple statements

Tags: c, linux, gcc, macros

I found some strange syntax while reading linux source code.
The container_of macro looks like

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({                      \
        const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);    \
        (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

what confused me is the syntax like ({statement1; statement2;})

I tried some simple code like

```
int a = {1;2;};
```

I compiled it with gcc. After running, 'a' seemed to be 2. But it couldn't be compiled with Microsoft VC++. Is this syntax an expanded feature of gcc? If so, how can I get the same effect without gcc expansion, like define multiple statements and return a value by using macro?

Comment: **Why do you ask?** The Linux kernel needs `gcc` (or a very compatible compiler, like recent versions of *TinyCC* or of *LLVM/Clang*) to be compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `({`...`})` syntax is a GCC extension, called [statement expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html).

The [typeof](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) is another GCC extension.

Both extensions are available in some other compilers, like [LLVM/Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) (or TinyCC).

The Linux kernel uses them quite often.

It would be quite difficult to avoid them. If you really wanted to, you might consider (and this is a non trivial task), some conversion from [GIMPLE](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GIMPLE) back to low-level, non-portable and unreadable C. You might use [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) for that (part of the job is done in its file `melt/xtramelt-c-generator.melt` by J.Salvucci).

Comment: Thank you. There are many masterly codes in Linux kernel that are valuable references for me. But sometimes I'm not allowed to use gcc, so I think I should try some other methods to get the similar effect in other compilers.

Comment: I have no idea who forbids you (and why) using `gcc` but you could then use `clang` which accepts same language extension.